# How do I create my own configuration file with the extension.yml and where should I place it?

Tags: c#, winforms, yaml

I have a winforms application.

I want to create 2 configuration files: one with the connection string, the other with the cache file paths.

How do I create my own configuration file with the extension.yml and where should I place it?

I created a configuration file inside the project, and registered it in Configuration Builder using https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration . But it seems to me that it is not correct to store the configuration file inside the project, and I do not want to use App.config since it should be compiled in App.config.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file contains YAML documents, you should use the extension `.yaml` which is what has been the official recommendation since at least September 2006 (twothousand and six).

For the lack of something like XDG_CONFIG_HOME on windows, in my code I expand the environment variable `APPDATA` (  i.e. %APPDATA% in windows explorer ) and create a namespace under that where I put configuration files, creating them with default values, if they don't exist already.

(Sorry, I have no tools to create  C# example code)